# SQL - getting details from a group by clause

Tags: sql

I can use the following query...

```
select ProcessTime, count(psid) as Cases
from cov.pslog 
group by ProcessTime 
having count(ProcessTime) > 1
order by ProcessTime asc
```

to generate results like this...

```
13:40   10
13:55   2
16:07   11
16:08   6
```

but what I really want is to see all the individual psid's for instances where there is more than 1 per ProcessTime value.  i.e. show me the 10 psids that were processed at 13:40.

I have tried so many variations, but this is as close as I can get.

Comment: Post (add to your question by using [Edit]) your source data consistent with this output.

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT * FROM cov.pslog WHERE processtime in ( [your select here])`

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM pslog WHERE processtime in (
    select ProcessTime
    from pslog
    group by ProcessTime
    having count(ProcessTime) > 1
    order by ProcessTime asc
)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0018a2/1